# Magento 2.2 Make fewer HTTP requests

Tags: magento2.2, http-request, gtmetrix

I Checked my `website` in the [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and i got one of the following suggestion

> This page has 95 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into
>   one.
>
> This page has 6 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.

[image]

**How can i solve this.I had google lot but still not got success.**

Comment: the problem that you have magento **2.2.** , you can ignore gtmetrix issues.

Comment: @MagenX yes you are right but i need to solve this issue

Comment: this is not a problem

Comment: @MagenX this problem is solved in magento1 website but client is need to solve this issue in M2 also :)

Answer (score 0):

I think combine the all javascript and css file hope this answer may ne help you

Javascript files are very often found in several external files. There is not always a need to have these files be separate as most javascript can be combined into one file and not affect the ways it functions.

Collecting all javascript files into one will really reduce the amount of time it takes to load your web pages because you are reducing the amount of things the web browser has to request before displaying your page.

And refer this links :-

https://mirasvit.com/knowledge-base/how-to-combine-javascript-files-in-magento-2.html

And Please check stylesheets issues :-

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html#css-merging-minification-and-performance

Comment: Thanks for answer here but in my website `css and js merge and minify` both still 0 showing http request

Comment: you refer the both links ??